# linux version of Free Pascal does not have Go32v2 process unit where to get process unit?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a problem with my compiler. It can't find the unit `Process` for **Go32v2**

Where can I download the unit and how do I install it?

Answer (score 0):

It usually is provided with Free Pascal, as package fcl-process:

E.g. in the fpc source:

```
 fpc-2.4.4/packages/fcl-process/src/process.pp
 fpc-2.4.4/packages/fcl-process/units/i386-win32/process.ppu
```